# Too many listeners in the node.js server side?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, express, middleware

right now I have the listeners code like the following. However, my server keeps telling me

```
(node) warning: possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit.
Trace
    at EventEmitter.addListener (events.js:160:15)
    at Hub.<anonymous> (/home/ec2-user/AjaxIM-retail/server/middleware/im/hub.js:88:33)
    at /home/ec2-user/AjaxIM-retail/server/libs/utils.js:43:23
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/home/ec2-user/AjaxIM-retail/server/libs/authentication/lp/index.js:75:33)
    at IncomingMessage.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:117:20)
    at _stream_readable.js:920:16
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
(node) warning: possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit.
```

I read some posts and some people advise me to "not add too many listeners"... Is that correct? What should I do?

```
   this.events.addListener('update', o_.bind(function(package) {
    if(this.clear != 0){
    delete this.sessions[this.clear];
    }
        var _package = package.toJSON();
        if(package.type == 'status' && package.status == 'offline') {
            var sids = Object.keys(this.sessions), sid, sess;
            for(sid in this.sessions) {
                sess = this.sessions[sid];
                if(sess.data('username') == package.username) {
                    if(sess.listeners.length)
                        sess.send(200, {type: 'goodbye'});
                    delete this.sessions[sid];
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }, this));
};

Hub.prototype.destroy = function(sid, fn) {
    this.set(sid, null, fn);
};

Hub.prototype.reap = function(ms) {
    var threshold = +new Date - ms,
        sids = Object.keys(this.sessions);
    for(var i = 0, len = sids.length; i < len; ++i) {
        var sid = sids[i], sess = this.sessions[sid];
        if(sess.lastAccess < threshold) {
         this.events.emit('update', new packages.Offline(sess.data('username')));
        }
    }
};


Hub.prototype.get = function(req, fn) {
    if(this.sessions[req.sessionID]) {
        fn(null, this.sessions[req.sessionID]);
    } else {
        this.auth.authenticate(req, o_.bind(function(data) {
            if(data) {
                var session = new User(req.sessionID, data);
                this.set(req.sessionID, session);
                this.auth.friends(req, data, o_.bind(function(friends) {
                    var friends_copy = friends.slice();
                    o_.values(this.sessions).filter(function(friend) {
                        return ~friends.indexOf(friend.data('username'));
                    }).forEach(function(friend) {
                        var username = friend.data('username');
                        friends_copy[friends_copy.indexOf(username)] =
                                            [username, friend.status()];
                    }, this);

                    session._friends(friends_copy);
                    session.events.addListener('status',
                        o_.bind(function(value, message) {
                            this.events.emit(
                                'update',
                                new packages.Status(session.data('username'),
                                                    value,
                                                    message)
                            );
                        }, this));
                    this.events.addListener('update',
                                      o_.bind(session.receivedUpdate, session));
                    this.set(req.sessionID, session);
                    fn(null, session);
                }, this));
            } else {
                fn();
            }
        }, this));
    }
};
```

I honestly think it is fine. Is there any problems? Please advise. Because my node.js server crushes every 10-20 hours now and keeps throwing me this listener warning and socket hang up error like this:

```
events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: socket hang up
    at SecurePair.error (tls.js:999:23)
    at EncryptedStream.CryptoStream._done (tls.js:695:22)
    at CleartextStream.read [as _read] (tls.js:496:24)
    at CleartextStream.Readable.read (_stream_readable.js:320:10)
    at EncryptedStream.onCryptoStreamFinish (tls.js:301:47)
    at EncryptedStream.g (events.js:175:14)
    at EncryptedStream.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:117:20)
    at finishMaybe (_stream_writable.js:354:12)
    at endWritable (_stream_writable.js:361:3)
    at EncryptedStream.Writable.end (_stream_writable.js:339:5)
    at EncryptedStream.CryptoStream.end (tls.js:633:31)
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's the code from node.js standart library, which triggers this warning: https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/events.js#L160-L176. So it basically just checking if your EventEmitter has more than 10 (by default) listeners attached. You can change this value by calling setMaxListeners (passing 0 means no limit).

So the warning itself has nothing to do with the crash. But it really can be caused by a leak, that is when you make a temporary object, then attach a listener function, which captures the object in a closure and then do not remove listener, which causes an object to stay in memory forever. Maybe this is your case. If not, just set the limit to an appropriate value, if it is — well, it means that the whole max listeners things really helps to find leaks.

Comment: @vkurchaktin Hi, can you share more details about how to close a listener? Everyone tells me to do so but i think my codes already did this... thanks sooo much for your help.

Comment: you need to call removeListener when you are done. To do that you need to have a reference to the listener function itself, so it is important that it is not anonymous.